# Store is not rendered in List Using sencha

Tags: extjs

I have created a form with 2 text field and button. I want to put the text field values in a list view when the user clicks a button. So I created a Model and Store for it. My List View code also in Main View. But I am facing a problem adding records in List View. It adds only the current records in List. It doesn't render records from store into List, and I click on refresh button but List display is empty. This means that data is not stored properly. Can you suggest to me what I did wrong in my code?

**Model**

```
   Ext.define("panellist.model.User",{
      extend:'Ext.data.Model',
      config:
        {

         fields:
         [
           {name:'name',type:'string'},
           {name:'add',type:'string'}
         ]

        }

    });
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define("panellist.store.Company",
{
   extend:'Ext.data.Store',
  config:
 {
       model:'panellist.model.User',
       autoload:true,
  proxy:
  {
        type:'localstorage',
        id:'mypanellist'
  } 
}


});
```

**Main.js**

```
 Ext.define('panellist.view.Main',
   {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',
        xtype: 'main',
        id:'mainview',
    requires: 
    [
       'Ext.TitleBar',
       'Ext.Panel',
       'Ext.List',
       'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'
    ],

    config: 
    {
     items:
    [
       {
         xtype:'titlebar',
         title:'welcome to sencha touch',
         docked:'top',

      },
      {

       xtype:'list',
       width:'100%',
       height:'100%',
       itemTpl:'{name},{add}',  
       store:"Company"

      },
      {
        xtype:'titlebar',
        docked:'bottom',

        items:
        [
        {
           xtype:'textfield',
           lablel:'enter the name',
           value:'enter the name',
           id:'t1',
           name:'txtname'
       },
       {
           xtype:'spacer',
       },
       {
           xtype:'textfield',
           value:'enter the address',
           name:'txtadd',
           id:'t2',
       },
       {
           xtype:'spacer',
       },

       {
           xtype:'button',
           text:'Add',
           action:'btnadd'
       }

       ]
     }
   ]}

});
```

**MyController.js**

```
var mdl=Ext.create('panellist.model.User');

Ext.define("panellist.controller.MyController",
{
             extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
config:
{
         refs:
        {
            // pass the id of the view
            nav:'#mainview'
         }


},
init:function()
{
              console.log("init is callled");
this.control({
'button[action=btnadd]':
 {
              tap:'insertrecords'
 }

});
},

launch:function()
{
           console.log("launch is callled");
},
insertrecords:function()
{
// fetch the records from field

var n=Ext.getCmp('t1').getValue();
var a=Ext.getCmp('t2').getValue();
// first store this values in model

mdl.set("name",n);
mdl.set("add",a);
// add model into the store
var store1=Ext.getStore("Company");

store1.add(mdl);
store1.sync();

console.log('records is added');


console.log(n);

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple suspect areas in your code.

Firs you should give your store a `storeId`.  This will allow you to find it with the `Ext.getStore()` in your controller.

Your **Main.js** should `require` the full path to your store since you reference it in one of your items.

```
requires: 
    [
       'Ext.TitleBar',
       'Ext.Panel',
       'Ext.List',
       'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage',
       'panellist.store.Company'      // <~ added 
    ],
```

Finally, as mentioned above, in your controller use the new storeId to get the store.

```
var store1 = Ext.getStore('newStoreId')
```

Give those a try and tell me what you come up with.

When you run your code, set a breakpoint at the `var store1 = Ext.getStore('..')` to ensure you are getting a store, and step through as you add your elements.  After the `sync()` you should be able to see your new items in the store.